# how to "break" from prompt

Tags: c#, botframework

So far, have this code :

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            var promptOptions = new PromptOptions<string>(
               "please choose one of the following options : ",
               tooManyAttempts: "you didn't choose valid option",
               options: options,
               promptStyler: new FacebookQuickRepliesPromptStyler(),
               attempts: 1
               );

            PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.ResumeAfterSelection, promptOptions);
        }
```

I would like to override PromptDialog.Choice function. I want that function to break or to forward activity to my root dialog if user didn't choose any option - **no matter how many attempts are defined**.

PromptDialog.Choice is not a virtual function, so i can't simply override : 
[image]

Edit : I tried to set attempts to 0, but than code throws an exception while executing. Attempts can't be set to 0.

Comment: try making the prompt optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a custom `PromptChoice`, then you need to inherit from the [PromptChoice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L908) class. The `PromptDialog.Choice` is just a static method to simplify the creation of the `PromptChoice` dialog.

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs) is an example of custom PromptChoice that supports cancellation.